# pgfornaments--switching to han graphics, troubleshooting

Tags: pgfornament

How do I tailor the following code to use pgfornament-han corner graphic #11 rather than pgfornament #42? Obviously I will need to change the bolded numbers, but no other strategy I am using seems to work.

See page 24 here: https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/pgfornament/doc/ornaments.pdf

```
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{
\begingroup
\setlength{\@tempdima}{2mm}
\setlength{\@tempdimb}{\paperwidth-\@tempdima-2cm}
\setlength{\@tempdimc}{\paperheight-\@tempdima}
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdima},\LenToUnit{\@tempdimc}){
\pgfornament[anchor=north west,width=2cm,color=darkbone,opacity=.5]**{41}**}\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdima},\LenToUnit{\@tempdima}){%
\pgfornament[anchor=south west,width=2cm,,color=darkbone,opacity=.5,symmetry=h]**{41}**}
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdimb},\LenToUnit{\@tempdimc}){%
\pgfornament[anchor=north east,width=2cm,,color=darkbone,opacity=.5,symmetry=v]**{41}**}
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdimb},\LenToUnit{\@tempdima}){%
\pgfornament[anchor=south east,width=2cm,,color=darkbone,opacity=.5,symmetry=c]**{41}**}
\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `object = pgfhan` to use the Han ornaments.

The `\@tempdimc` will get overwritten before the third ornament which is why I'm using simple TeX macros here.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[object=pgfhan]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\definecolor{darkbone}{HTML}{836b56}
\makeatletter
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\@@tempdima{2mm}%
    \edef\@@tempdimb{\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-\@tempdima-2cm}%
    \edef\@@tempdimc{\the\dimexpr\paperheight-\@tempdima}%
    \put(\@@tempdima,\@@tempdimc){%
      \pgfornament[anchor=north west,width=2cm,color=darkbone!50]{11}}%
    \put(\@@tempdima,\@@tempdima){%
      \pgfornament[anchor=south west,width=2cm,color=darkbone!50,symmetry=h]{11}}%
    \put(\@@tempdimb,\@@tempdimc){%
      \pgfornament[anchor=north east,width=2cm,color=darkbone!50,symmetry=v]{11}}%
    \put(\@@tempdimb,\@@tempdima){%
      \pgfornament[anchor=south east,width=2cm,color=darkbone!50,symmetry=c]{11}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: The above solution does not work when embedded into the rest of my code.